# Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request

Tags: php, google-plus

I'm try to  google plus api for third party log in on my web site.

I use class Google_Client method createAuthUrl to generate URI for user log in,
and the page will redirect to my web site page to complete the authorization,
but when I use method Google_Client.authenticate to check the result,I got following error,

Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_request

so,how can I check where does the error from? maybe in session or somewhere

Comment: Rfer https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer and go step by step

Comment: what did you do with the authentication code from the callback?

Comment: You can use that code to fetch a token for your server, as well. Simply pass the code to your server, which can then exchange the code for an access token so that both your client and server are authorized. https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem myself. As it turns out, I wasn't consistent in de construction of the client. Make sure that your redirect uri does not include the returned query string containing the authentication code!

For example this will not work:

```
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

REQUEST_URI will be different when the user returns from Google.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. In my case, the javascript client uses the Google API (gapi) to grant an access token to the server using the grantOfflineAccess method. According to the Google guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_6_send_the_authorization_code_to_the_server the grantOfflineAccess method is called with a json parameter ({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}) if there are no redirects defined for the google app.  In this case, the server must call $client->setRedirectURi('postmessage'); prior to calling the authenticate method.